# link_to new_product with brand id RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working in Ruby on Rails, I have a products and brands, and when I'm in a Brand I want to create a new product that belongs to that brand, then I want to link_to with the brand_id.
How can I do that?

```
<%= link_to 'New Product', new_product_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary'%>
```

brand model

```
has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
```

product model

```
  belongs_to :brand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routes:

```
resources :brands do
    resources :products
end
```

The link:

```
link_to "New product", new_brand_product_path(@brand), class: "btn"
```

If you can create products outside of a brand, you might want to use a scope in your routes:

```
resources :brands do
    scope module: "brand_scope" do
        resources :products
    end
end
```

This way, you can have a separate controller to create products within a brand: `app/controllers/brand_scope/products_controller.rb`, but the path (`new_brand_product_path(@brand)`) is still the same.

---

In products controller, `new` action:

```
@brand = Brand.find(params[:brand_id])
@product = Product.new
```

In `views/brand_scope/products/_new.html.erb`:

```
form_for [@brand, @product] do |f|
```

Comment: perfect then in the controller

        @brand = Brand.find(params[:id])

but in the form_for how can I specify the brand_id?

I new in RoR
Thanks